# Unable to run CASE WHEN for array in Spring Boot repository

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to run this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.*\n" +
            "FROM tlm_trade t\n" +
            "left join tlm_trade_nugget n\n" +
            "on t.trade_nugget_id=n.id\n" +
            "where \n" +
            "(year(t.created_date) in (case when ?1 is null then year(t.created_date) else ?1 end))\n" +
            ";", nativeQuery = true)
    List<TlmTrade> findByFilter(Set<Integer> year);
;
```

When I pass this as the argument

```
[2021,2020,2019]
```

Got this error instead

> SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case when ... end` is an `expression`, they **evaluate to a single value**.

In your example you are hoping that you could use a `case expression` to act as "dynamic sql". i.e. if ?1 is null, then insert the term "year(t.created_date)" but if ?1 is not null then insert ?1

You cannot do that.

It would make more sense to do this by branching before forming @Query, one branch for ?1 being null, and another which uses ?1

Also, avoid case expressions in where clauses, it is better to express filters in binary terms such as this, using parentheses where needed:

```
"where (?1 IS NULL AND year(t.created_date) = '2021' )\n"
```

?1 by the way will need to equal something, or be greater than something etc. ?1 by itself will not form a filtering condition.